# Receive events via HTTP transport and view the output on the console with JSON input data

Tags: wso2, siddhi, wso2-streaming-integrator

I am following the ReceiveAndcount example at siddhi editor, with my own data, for consulting to an external URL which needs input data to response (token, dates and device_id). This query should return a JSON with a date, a boolean and three float data.

My code is as follows:

```
@Source(type = 'http',
    receiver.url='some_url',
    @map(type='json',
        @attributes('Token'='my_token_AAABBBCCC',
           'StartDate'='2019-01-30 15:57:00',
           'EndDate'='2019-01-30 15:58:00',
           'Device'='device_id')))
define stream SomeStream (
    date string,
    ValueIsValid bool,
    DATA1 float,
    DATA2 float,
    DATA3 float
)

-- Destination
@sink(type='log')
define stream MyOutputStream (EA1 float, EA2 float);

-- Show the selected data
@info(name='queryEA1_EA2')
from SomeStream
select EA1, EA2
insert into MyOutputStream;
```

I am not able to get any result, only an "TestingReceiveAndCount.siddhi - Siddhi AppTestingReceiveAndCount is in faulty state." error in the console.

I have checked the siddhi documentation and I am not sure if I am passing the input data to the URL correctly to get a response

Comment: I am bit confused on the requirement. Do you want to receive HTTP requests to SP or send HTTP request and get results from SP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send HTTP requests and receive responses in WSO2 SP, you have to use,
http-request(sink) and http-response(source). Please see the code below,

```
@sink(type = 'http-request', sink.id = 'HttpReqRes', publisher.url = 'url_to_invoke', method = 'GET',
    @map(type = 'json'))
define stream localTestEventReq (token string, startdate string, enddate string, device string);

@source(type = 'http-response', sink.id = 'HttpReqRes', http.status.code = '200', 
    @map(type = 'json')) 
define stream localTestEventRes2xx(data1 string, data1 string);
```

Here, when you invoke the localTestEventReq with the value for the stream attributes(or [simulate](https://docs.wso2.com/display/SP430/Simulating+a+Single+Event) for testing), a request will be sent out and if the response is of code 200, an event would arrive in localTestEventRes2xx. Please see the [api docs](https://wso2-extensions.github.io/siddhi-io-http/api/1.0.45/#http-request-sink) for the above sink and source.